# How to use Notification.BigPictureStyle with long summary text?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to show notification with big picture(BigPictureStyle) and big text(BigTextStyle). How can I do it?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361533/android-notification-big-picture-style-and-big-text-style

Comment: Please elaborate on how it fails to work.

Comment: It shows big title in single line. I need multi line (BigTextStyle)

Comment: Please check this solution, it will HELP u https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757879/3946958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setstyle only allows either BigPictureStyle or BigTextStyle. If you need a non-standard notification style, you may have to use a custom notification layout.

See [Change Notification Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout) and [How to make an image fit a custom 256dp Big Picture Notification in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909151/how-to-pre-scale-an-image-to-fit-a-256dp-big-picture-notification-in-android) on using a custom notification layout. For multi-line long text use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` for the TextView.  The latter answer contains an example of custom big picture.